# how to stream a online radio without any stuck over streaming?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

how to stream a online radio without any buffering after the player is played. It should buffered for few sec for continue playing the radio,but it get stuck for few sec and playing.

my Aync task:
 class Player extends AsyncTask {
        private ProgressDialog progress;

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Boolean prepared;
        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);




            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    intialStage = true;
                    playPause = false;
                    control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("IllegarArgument", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            prepared = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progress.isShowing()) {
            progress.cancel();
        }
        Log.d("Prepared", "//" + result);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        media.stop();

        intialStage = false;
    }

    public Player() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        this.progress.setMessage("Buffering...");
        media.start();
    }
}
public  void mute1(View v){
    speaker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mute.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
    media.setVolume(0,0);
    seekbar.setClickable(false);
    seekbar.setFocusable(false);
    seekbar.setEnabled(false);

}
public  void speaker1(View v){
    speaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
    media.setVolume(1,1);
    seekbar.setClickable(true);
    seekbar.setFocusable(true);
    seekbar.setEnabled(true);

}
```

how to get my player prepare for the online radio without any streaming after player is started.

Please Help me..

my source is:

```
        if (playPause) {
            control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            new Player().cancel(true);
            media.stop();
            media.reset();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            media.stop();

            playPause = false;
        } else {
            control.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            if (intialStage) {
                new Player()
                        .execute("http://streaming.shoutcast.com/MUKILFMRADIO");
            } else {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            }
            playPause = true;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Exoplayer than media player.ExoPlayer is an application level media player for Android. It provides an alternative to Android’s MediaPlayer API for playing audio and video both locally and over the Internet. ExoPlayer supports features not currently supported by Android’s MediaPlayer API, including DASH and **SmoothStreaming** adaptive playbacks. Unlike the MediaPlayer API, ExoPlayer is easy to customize and extend, and can be updated through Play Store application updates. This links give you better idea about Exoplayer.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: i want to play my online radio without any buffering. if i change my mediaplayer to ExoPlayer my min api level is 19 it may affect by that..